# How to fix stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string when also using array

Tags: php, parameters, stripslashes

I have a php form that passes values to an email. The form has both single values and arrays. I'm getting the following error and I can't fix it.

Warning: stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/...... line 147

If tried to add

```
if(is_array$cleanvalue = stripslashes($value);
```

Line 147 is as follows:

```
#clean fields for repost or display
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
$cleanvalue = stripslashes($value);
$repostvalue = stripquotes($cleanvalue);
$hiddenhtml .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$key\" 
value=\"$repostvalue\">\n";
${$key} = $cleanvalue;
}
```

Upon submitting the form, I get the following error, but not until the entire form is filled out.
Warning: stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/...... line 147

Comment: `if(isarray($value)` should work, show the actual code you tried.

Comment: `#clean fields for repost or display` – you’re using the wrong methods for that to begin with. Stripping slashes and quotes would _falsify_ the data I originally entered, what would be the point of _that_ kind of treatment? Imagine a site like SO here doing this, we’d barely be able to post any kind of code, if such nonsensical measures were to be applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using `is_array()` and mapping `stripslashes()` on each value if it is:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        ${key} = array_map('stripslashes', $value);
    } else {
        $cleanvalue = stripslashes($value);
    } 

    $repostvalue = stripquotes($cleanvalue);
    $hiddenhtml .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$repostvalue\">\n";
    ${$key} = $cleanvalue;
}
```

It looks like `stripquotes()` may be a custom function? You'll need to modify it similarly. You will need to loop over your values differently if you want to output them in html again, maybe something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        ${key} = array_map('stripslashes', $value);
    } else {
        $cleanvalue = stripslashes($value);
    } 

    $repostvalue = stripquotes($cleanvalue);

    if (is_array($value))
    {
        foreach($repostvalue as $repost) {
            $hiddenhtml .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$key[]\" value=\"$repost\">\n";
        }

    } else {
        $hiddenhtml .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$repostvalue\">\n";
    }

    ${$key} = $cleanvalue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! That was huge. I really appreciate it.